# WSGI Mistake in Django

Tags: django, server, wsgi

I try to deploy my project at pythonanywhere.
My structure

```
   MyBlog                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
│   ├── blog                                                                                                                                         
│   │   ├── blog                                                                                                                                     
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py                                                                                                                          
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc                                                                                                                         
│   │   │   ├── settings.py                                                                                                                          
│   │   │   ├── settings.pyc                                                                                                                         
│   │   │   ├── urls.py                                                                                                                              
│   │   │   ├── urls.pyc                                                                                                                             
│   │   │   └── wsgi.py                                                                                                                              
│   │   ├── db.sqlite3                                                                                                                               
│   │   ├── manage.py                                                                                                                                
│   │   ├── posts                                                                                                                                    
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py                                                                                                                          
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc                                                                                                                         
             .........
```

My wsgi file at server

```
    import os
import sys
path = '/home/Ivan/MyBlog'  # use your own username here
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'blog.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I got the mistake:

```
Error running WSGI application
ImportError: No module named blog.settings
File "/var/www/ivan_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

what's the problem?

Comment: `blog.blog.settings` is that work nor no?

Comment: Error running WSGI application
 ImportError: No module named blog.blog.settings File "/var/www/ivan_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
 application = get_wsgi_application()

Answer (score 2):

Try to change that setting:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'blog.blog.settings'
```

UPDATE:

So change path with:

```
path = '/home/Ivan/MyBlog/blog'
```

and use with:

```
 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'blog.settings'
```

Comment: I dont get this "use with 'blog.settings' when should I use it?

Comment: @question1 one more update, should help else need more detail look at your settings

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- the second option (with one "blog" in the path, and one in the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`) is the best option there.